# Woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: wordpress, forms, function, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I have a checkbox on the checkoutpage in my woocommerce site. I want to write a function where if this checkbox is checked then a div will dropdown with additional information.

The checkbox has an id of #unattended

However I have no idea where to start : /

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, good question.  Here's an example (I commented the code) to show you how it's done:

```js
function showInfo(box) {

  if (box.checked == true) { // if the checkbox is checked

    document.getElementById('information').className = "show";
    // show the div

  } else if (box.checked == false) { // if it's not

    document.getElementById('information').className = "hide";
    // hide the div

  }

}
```

```css
#information { /* This styles the div and makes it in the center of the page */
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.hide { /* these are the styles for when the div is hidden */
  top: -20px;
  transition: top 0.6s;
}
.show { /* these are the styles for when the div is visible */
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div id="information" class="hide">Put lots and lots and lots and lots of information here.</div><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="unattended" onclick="showInfo(this)" />
```

I hope that this helps you out!  If you need additional help, please comment below.